# Are controllers inside the application layer or infrastructure layer? Should I even use controllers in Clean Architecture?

Tags: node.js, express, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

As far as I can understand, Clean Architecture/DDD states that your use cases can be triggered by anything, let it be a HTTP request or GUI, correct?

I am trying to emulate that, but I am not really sure if I am doing it correctly.

Inside my `infrastructure` folder, I have routers. For example:

```
import express from 'express'
import UserController from '../controllers/user_controller.js'
import ExpressRouterAdapter from './ExpressRouterAdapter.js'

export default function UsersRouter () {
  const router = express.Router()

  router.route('/:username').get(ExpressRouterAdapter.adapt(UserController.getUser))

  return router
}
```

(`ExpressRouterAdapter` is just an adapter that transforms Express requests into a simple httpRequest JS object)

And here is my `GetUser` controller:

```js
export class GetUser {
  constructor ({ FindUserService }) {
    this.findUser = FindUserService
  }

  async handle (httpRequest = {}) {
    try {
      const { username } = httpRequest.params

      if (!username) {
        return {
          statusCode: 400,
          body: 'Missing username parameter.'
        }
      }

      const user = await this.findUser.execute(username) 

      // ...
```

I have a few questions:

1. Should I even have controllers? Should the Router direct it to the use-case/service directly?
2. ^^ The reason I ask that is because my controllers are really HTTP centered. For example some of them are called: `PostUser`, `GetUser`, `DeleteUser`. So I am guessing they should be inside the `infrastructure` folder, right?

I am guessing that controllers are ONLY used if your delivery mechanism is a web app, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right. There's nothing really to do with DDD because DDD is about contexts and language, but for clean architecture and ports and adapters that's the correct thought.

Normally, you would have the structure like this:

[image]

So, your application exposes an API that represents a port and you can connect different *edge* components that implement a physical delivery protocol of different kinds to talk to your application.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the clarification. So controllers are just adapters, and the ports would be the use cases, correct? So there is no issue for a controller to receive explicitly a HTTP request like I did up there?

Thank you

Comment: and also, controllers are also presenters, right? since they send a request and also return it

Comment: A presenter works directly with the view. Controllers only return the model. But, it's not in the scope of this question.